# How do I step through an executable file using gdb?

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, gdb

What I'm attempting to do is to record the values stored in registers at each assembly instruction of a function. All I have is just the executable file to work with. I've figured how to get the asm layout but just having a hard time with stepping through that. When I use "b 1" command to set a break point that I could start stepping through from, I get an error "No line 1 in file "../sysdeps/i386/dl-procinfo.c". Here's a screenshot to show the commands I've entered so far:

[image]

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the memory address rather than the line number. Or the function name if you know it.

Comment: Use `start` instead of `run` to set a one-time breakpoint at the top of `main`.  Or `starti` to stop before the very first user-space instruction (in the `_start` entry point of your executable or of `ld.so`, depending on what type of executable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function name or a memory address when putting a breakpoint instead or compile without optimizations if you want line numbers.

```
(gdb) b main // will put a break point at start of function main
(gdb) r      // run
```

Alternatively, use `start` command which sets a temporary breakpoint on main() and starts executing.

Use `n` to move to next instruction and `si` to step into a function / label.

To display the `registers`, you can use `info regs` command or `i r`. Alternatively, use registers layout, which is much better. To get the value inside a particular register, use `print`, e.g `print $rax`.

```
(gdb) layout regs
```